# File program shows error

Tags: java, file, runtime-error

For the first time my file program ran very well.  But then after when I want to run it shows error. What might be the reason?

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

public class FileSentenceRead {

    /**
     * @param args
     * @throws IOException 
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        /*Scanner sn=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter file name");
        String fname=sn.next();*/
        FileInputStream fis=new FileInputStream("textfile.text");
        int size=fis.available();
        byte bt[]= new byte[size];
        fis.read(bt);
        String pr=new String(bt);
        System.out.println(pr);
        String[] pr1=pr.split("\\s|\\.");
//      @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
//      HashSet set=new HashSet();
        StringBuffer s=null;
        StringBuffer ss=new StringBuffer();
        for(int i=0;i<pr1.length;i++){
            s= new StringBuffer(pr1[i]);
//          System.out.print(s.reverse()+" ");
            s=s.reverse();
            ss.append(s+" ");
        }
        System.out.println(ss);
    }
}
```

Here is my error message

```
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: You have posted the stacktrace but not the error message. Post the message as well

Comment: One good practice is to close the streams whenever you are opening one.

Comment: It shows Exception in thread main. Could not find the main class : textfile.text . Program will exit.

Comment: Are you sure it runs first time? if yes then it should run every subsequent time as well. Your code runs fine on my machine always.

Answer (score 1):

> Could not find the main class : textfile.text

It looks like you are not executing the correct command line. Your command line call should be something like this (assuming you are executing it from where classes are generated):

```
java -cp . FileSentenceRead
```

or if you put it in a package:

```
java -cp . com.foo.mypackage.FileSentenceRead
```

If you are running from Eclipse, you may have put your program arguments in the VM arguments, which will produce the same error. Then just move your program arguments in the correct field and remove them from the VM arguments field.

Comment: Hei Potel U r right. It work now Thanks 4 ur valuable time to help me out....Hv a great day...If u don't mind what is your personal E-mail id.

Answer (score 0):

How are you running your class. Your main class name is `FileSentenceRead` and not `textfile.text` as you are seeing in your error message. I ran your code it runs fine on my machine always.

May be some issue with your launch configuration or in the command you are using to run it.

Comment: Mera system me run nehi hota he pata nehi kya problem hei? Kuch idea...please

Comment: I run this class by right clicking and run as java application in Eclipse. It ran for the first time and I closed eclipse tool and again I opened to run , at that time it won't work....

Comment: ok, So check your `Run Configurations` which got created for running this, the name of the *Main class* should be `FileSentenceRead` and not `textfile.text`.

Answer (score 0):

yes **Himanshu Mohta** is correct. I have checked the code with

FileInputStream fis=new FileInputStream("c:\\tmp\\textfile.text");

and **some text here** as text in the text file and it returns :

some text here

emos txet ereh

So, nothing wrong with the code, check your filesystem folder security read/write permissions